# Does sed -n '1s/pattern/substitute/p' parse the whole file or quit after line 1?

Tags: unix, sed

When `sed` executes with a 1-line address (line 1) and a substitution thereon, example:

```
$ sed -n '1s/foo/bar/p' <<EOF
foo will be replaced, this is line 1
are these lines still processed?
Hard to check.
EOF
```

does sed continue to read/parse the remainder of the file or does it quit after the named address?   I'm on a very fast system and timings appear as though it does stop, but without a `q` command given, wanted to make sure.

Comment: The `q` command prints whatever is in the pattern space then exits the program, so you could write: `sed '1s/foo/bar/;q'`. In GNU sed, the `Q` exits the program without printing the pattern space and both `q` and `Q` can have exit codes (default is 0) e.g. `q1` or `Q255`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it definitely doesn't stop on my version of `sed` (GNU sed version 4.2.1).

I created a file with many lines (203118592) by running `yes` for a few seconds and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>:

```
$ yes > file
```

That creates a huge file with a bunch of lines with "y." Then I ran your `sed` command to replace "y" with "n" (instead of "foo" with "bar"), and it took quite some time:

```
$ wc -l file
203118592 file
$ time sed -n '1s/y/n/p' file
n

real    0m9.335s
user    0m9.237s
sys     0m0.068s
```

You just didn't create a sufficiently large file to see the effect. :)

Also, just for reference, if I do use `q`, it quits as expected:

```
$ time sed -n '1s/y/n/p ;q' file
n

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```